# Writing CityEngine code?

Tags: cityengine

I'm new to CityEngine and struggling to put together code for a zoning rule that requires buildings to have a graduated height based on what's called the context transition edge. Max height is a ratio in relation to distance from the property line.

I understand basic CGA but need help thinking this through.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  For coding questions you need to include a code snippet that shows what you have tried and where you are stuck.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to do that.